Google Sign-In Fails on Android Emulator: "Couldn't Sign In
I’m experiencing an issue with Google Sign-In on the Android emulator. While Google Sign-In works perfectly on iOS emulators, it fails to load the login screen on the Android emulator, eventually showing "Couldn't sign in". This issue persists across different applications, including the Play Store, YouTube, and my Flutter app. I am using a Mac. The wifi work perfectly on the android emulators and the google play service are enabled. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?
Thank in advance!
I tried to change the network and nothings seems to work

You didn't provide details to identify the causing issue correctly. But the possibility is your Emulator doesn't have Google Play Services installed.
Create a new Emulator that has Google Play Services active.
There is an icon of Play while creating the emulator indicating if this emulator has google play service.

